# Doubt in the sentence "I promise I will live up to your expectations and even exceed those."

Tags: grammar, british-english, email

I'm writing an email to my Professor, who supervised my MSc degree research project. I am requesting him to give me a PhD project. I am thinking to add the sentence mentioned below, in the email:

"I promise I will live up to your expectations and even exceed those."

Is the above sentence grammatically correct?

Comment: ... exceed **them**.

Answer (score 1):

This is very close - I would probably write it as "I promise I will live up to your expectations and hopefully exceed them."

Changing "those" to "them" was essential, while changing "even" to "hopefully" is purely a matter of taste, others may disagree with me on the latter.

Answer (score 1):

"... even exceed them"

Rhetorically this sentence is rather pointless.  How do you know your professor's expectations?  How do you know you will live up to them?  This may be your intention now, but things can go wrong.  If you don't put this sentence will your professor think that you intend to do badly?

Every sentence should work to prove that you are the right person for the PhD. Does this sentence do that?

Answer (score 0):

Living up to the expectations, and exceeding them are different, that's why we can't have them both written definitely. So, you can choose one, or, say that "I'll try my very best to exceed them", or "hopefully exceed your expectations."